# JSF pass Parameter to dataTable value

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, datatable, xhtml, parameter-passing

my input for the datatable: `List<SelectionDto<PersonContainer>>`.

`PersonContainer` contains: `List<QuestionContainer>`

`QuestionContainer` contains: `Date date1, Date date2`

in normal words: every Person has a List of `questionContainer` (normally it is only 1 container). 2 of the questions in this container are dates. One of the dates must be filled. Maybe both are filled.

I have 3 `dataTables`, the first shows given input. In the last column is a button that executes a javascript which starts a dialog that contains the second and third `dataTable`.
The 2. `dataTable` should display the first date, if it exists
The 3. `dataTable` should display the second date, if it exists

Thats the table that works fine:

```
<t:dataTable id="tableId" value="#{value}" var="dto" rowIndexVar="row">
      <ui:insert />
      <h:column>...</h:column>
      ...
      <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{dto.src.person.quesions[0].date1}" />
        <h:commandLink value="Extend" styleClass="button">
          <f:ajax render=":messages" onevent="showDialog" />
          <f:setPropertyAcionListener target="#{Bean.currentRow}" value="#{row}" />
        </h:commandLink>
</t:dataTable>
```

Here is the problem: `[Bean.currentRow]` is always 0. I debugged it, and in the Bean the value is passed the right way, but not in the `dataTables`

```
<h:panelgroup id="dialog" layout="block" styleClass="dN">
  <h:dataTable value="#{value[Bean.currentRow].src.person.questions}" var="questions" rendered="#{not empty value[Bean.currentRow].src.person.questions[0].date1}">
  <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{questions.date1}" />
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <h:inputText value="#{questions.date1}" styleClass="datalizeMe" />
  </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
  <h:dataTable>
    //same with date2
  </h:dataTable> 
</h:panelGroup>
```

So when I click the Extend-button, a window opens and it displays the date from the first Person in the list, instead of the person on whick button i clicked.
How can I pass the row-index to the `value[Index]` of the second and third dataTable ?

Answers in german or english please :)